# No Twitter accounts yet on iOS Device

Tags: ios, twitter

If a user does not have a Twitter account installed on their device is there a good way to prompt them to install one and take them to the Settings panel to do so? I know before iOS 5.1 there was a URL to take them to the settings screen, but I think that no longer works. It seems pretty sloppy to tell them they do not have an account and just leave 'em hanging.

Answer (score 0):

`openURL` has not been deprecated. At least not according to the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a).

Just use a UIAlertView to ask whether the user would like to add an account. If they say yes, call the following line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

Comment: I know openURL is not deprecated, but the URL prefs:root=TWITTER no longer works.